# Squid reverse proxy with optional SSL

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up squid as a load-balancing reverse-proxy, and I'm having a bit of trouble with the SSL. One of the site's applications checks to see if a site is loaded over SSL, and behaves differently if that is the case, so I need SSL connections to be proxied over SSL, and non-SSL connections to be proxied without it.

Right now, the squid server accepts connections over HTTP and HTTPS, but it only **makes** connections over HTTP to the upstream servers.

The interesting part of my squid configuration looks like this:

```
http_port 80 vhost vport
https_port 443 vhost vport  cert=/etc/cert.pem key=/etc/cert.key
cache_peer 10.0.0.10 parent 80 0 originserver round-robin
cache_peer 10.0.0.11 parent 80 0 originserver round-robin
```

Is there a simple way to tell it to proxy the SSL connections upstream over SSL, while leaving the others alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** (actually tried this from my squid...):

```
acl is_ssl port 443
https_port 443 cert=<yourcert> key=<yourkey> accel name=site_ssl defaultsite=<y\
our_external_site>
cache_peer <your_internal_ssl> parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=\
DONT_VERIFY_PEER name=site_ssl
cache_peer_access site_ssl allow is_ssl
cache_peer_access site_ssl deny !is_ssl

acl nonssl port 80
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=<your_external_site>  name=site_nonssl
cache_peer <your_internal_nonssl> parent 80 0 no-query name=site_nonssl origins\
erver
cache_peer_access site_nonssl allow nonssl
cache_peer_access site_nonssl deny !is_nonssl
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW HERE:

you want something like

```
cache_peer 10.0.0.11 parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER name=site_ssl
acl sites_server_3 dstdomain site_ssl
cache_peer_access site_ssl allow ssl_servers
http_access allow ssl_servers
```

Comment: I tried the configuration above and when the lines related to port 80 are added to the conf file it works fine. However as soon as I add the lines related port 443 (more precisely lines 2 and 3) the squid service exit with the following error: `No valid signing SSL certificate configured for HTTPS_port [::]:443`. I'm using a self-signed certificate created with then openssl command line. What about your certificate ? How did you generate it ?

Comment: I figured out that the certificate must be trusted in order to be used by squid so I created a certificate with my CA and added the root certificate as specified here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000022/1423806)